# Using inst/extdata with vignette during package checking R 2.14.0

Tags: r, package, r-package

I have a package which contains a csv file which I put in inst/extdata per R-exts.  This file is needed for the vignette.  If I Sweave the vignette directly, all works well.  When I run R --vanilla CMD check however, the check process can't find the file.  I know it has been moved into an .Rcheck directory during checking and this is probably part of the problem.  But I don't know how to set it up so both direct Sweave and vignette building/checking works.

The vignette contains a line like this:

```
EC1 <- dot2HPD(file = "../inst/extdata/E_coli/ecoli.dot",
node.inst = "../inst/extdata/E_coli/NodeInst.csv",
```

and the function dot2HPD accesses the file via:

```
    ni <- read.csv(node.inst)
```

Here's the error message:

```
    > tab <- read.csv("../inst/extdata/E_coli/NodeInst.csv")
Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '../inst/extdata/E_coli/NodeInst.csv': No such file or directory

  When sourcing ‘HiveR.R’:
Error: cannot open the connection
Execution halted
```

By the way, this is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886644/how-to-point-to-a-directory-in-an-r-package/1886891#1886891) but that info seems outdated and doesn't quite cover this territory.

I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using `system.file` instead of hardcoded relative paths?

```
EC1 <- dot2HPD(file = system.file("inst", "extdata", "E_coli", "ecoli.dot", package = "your_package+name"))
node.inst <- system.file("inst", "extdata", "E_coli", "NodeInst.csv", package = "your_package_name")
```

Comment: Thanks Max.  I tried it, but it returns an empty string.  Looking at ?system.file, there is the implication that the package must already be installed (because there is a lib.loc argument).  Perhaps what is needed is the idea of system.file but evaluated in the checking environment.

Comment: omit `inst`; that directory is removed during installation -- `system.file("extdata", "E_coli", "ecoli.dot", package="your_package+name")`

Comment: I see another problem.  The file of interest is in BAH/packages/HiveR/inst/extdata/E_coli/  However, during check the "inst" folder disappears, and instead the path to the file of interest is now: BAHpackages/HiveR.Rcheck/HiveR/extdata/E_coli/NodeInst.csv

Comment: @MartinMorgan Thanks Martin.  Your approach works for building and checking the package, but does not work on a direct Sweave.  However, I can live with that!